# Generic bi-dir one-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I would like to know if there exists some way to use generics in JPA 2.0?

Consider this scenario:

```
@Entity
public class GenericPhoto<T> implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;

  @NotNull
  private byte[] file;

  @ManyToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH })
  @JoinColumn(name = "PARENTID", nullable = false)
  @NotNull
  private T parent;

  //...
}

@Entity
public Car {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
  private Set<GenericPhoto<Car>> photos;

  //...
}

@Entity
public Truck {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
  private Set<GenericPhoto<Truck>> photos;

  //...
}
```

I hope the code explains it all. I simply want to make a generic class for photo, which I think makes it easier to implement services etcetera.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a generic, it is similar to not typing the field (i.e. Object parent), so you need to tell JPA how to map the relationship.  For this you can use targetEntity in JPA.

For this to work, you will need a common superclass to Car and Truck i.e. Auto, and set the targetEntity in the @ManyToOne to Auto (you may also consider moving photos up to Auto).

If you can't use inheritance for some reason, (it is best to use inheritance).  Then if you use EclipseLink you could use a @VariableOneToOne relationship.

Comment: Thank you, I will go for inheritance =)